# An olympiad Geometry problem involving triangles

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, triangles

In the triangle $ABC\,$ we denote by $O$ and $I$ the circumcenter and incenter respectively. The perpendicular bisectors of the line segments $IA$, $IB$ and $IC$ pairwise intersect thus defining the triangle $A_1B_1C_1$ Prove that $\vec {OI}=\vec {OA_1}+\vec {OB_1}+\vec {OC_1}$

Hi there. Im a high schooler new to olympiad geometry. Ive been unable to solve this problem despite repeated angle chasing could someone give a solution?Note I dont know stuff like projective geometry and hard lemmas so a simple proof would be most appreciated.

Comment: You may want to see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for formatting

Comment: it doesnt have answers to how to input vector arrows

Comment: I just did it as an edit

Comment: Point 14 covers that

Comment: got it thanks doe

Answer (score 1):

In another words, it is enough to prove that $O$ is circumcenter of $A_1B_1C_1$ and $I$ is it orthocenter (and this is so called Hamilton's theorem).

And this is easy to prove. Say $AI,BI,CI$ cuts circumcircle of $ABC$ at $A',B'C'$ respectively. Then $A'B'$ is perpendicular bisector of $CI$ (can you prove it your self?) and so on and $A',B',C'$ are intersection points of those bisectors.

Comment: how is that enough.

Comment: I dont get how to prove the circumcircles are the same or I is the orthocenter.Could someone give a proper proof ?